# Misunderstading functional derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

I am having troubles executing functional derivatives, I have just read [this](https://cds.cern.ch/record/1383342/files/978-3-642-14090-7_BookBackMatter.pdf) resource together with the [Wikipedia page on functional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative).

In the latter, under the example section, they consider $V[\rho] = \int \frac{\rho(r)}{r}$. Using the definition the functional derivative we get
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{\delta V[\rho(r)]}{\delta \rho(r)} \phi(r) dr = \left( \frac{d}{d\epsilon} \int \frac{\rho(r) + \epsilon \phi(r)}{r}dr \biggr\rvert_{\epsilon \to 0} \right).
\end{equation}
I don't understand the next step when they evaluate the above expression to
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{1}{r} \phi(r) dr.
\end{equation}

How did $\rho(r)$ vanish? My attempt to the solution was to differentiate away $\epsilon$ in the integrand which would give

\begin{equation}
\left( \frac{d}{d\epsilon} \int \frac{\rho(r) + \epsilon \phi(r)}{r}dr \biggr\rvert_{\epsilon \to 0} \right) = \left(  \int \frac{\rho(r) +\frac{d}{d\epsilon} \epsilon \phi(r)}{r}dr \biggr\rvert_{\epsilon \to 0} \right)  = \left(  \int \frac{\rho(r) + 1 \times \phi(r)}{r}dr \biggr\rvert_{\epsilon \to 0} \right) = \int \frac{\rho(r) +  \phi(r)}{r}dr.
\end{equation}

What is it that I am misunderstanding?

After my understanding, my goal is to evaluate $\delta e^{f(x)} h_{\mu \nu} (x)$. It would be nice to apply the above method to this example.

Comment: The derivative of a constant is zero. If $\rho$ isn't a function of $\epsilon$ then $d\rho/d\epsilon =0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Posting this answer so this question can be officially marked as answered.)

As @Sal mentioned in the comments, you can separate the integral into
$$
\int \frac{\rho(r)}{r} \; \text{d}r
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
\varepsilon \int \frac{\phi(r)}{r}  \; \text{d}r
$$
With respect to $\varepsilon > 0$, the second term is constant, so the one-sided derivatives with respect to $\varepsilon > 0$ are
$$
0
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
\int \frac{\phi(r)}{r}  \; \text{d}r,
$$
as required.